# Write() on the same terminal line as the read() function

Tags: c, input, terminal, output

I am currently writing a tiny POSIX terminal emulator to learn more about C.
I finished writing a working terminal with several builtins (env, exit, etc.) and now want to implement an auto-complete feature using a linked list.

In order to do so, I need to be able to be use the `write()` function on the same line as the `read()` function I am using.

However I only seem to be able to do so on the next terminal line - I probably am missing out on something really obvious could not find it. I tried joining the string I got with "\r" but it did not work.

Here is what I wrote :

```
#include "./libft/libft.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int     main()
{
    char *buf;
    char *result;
    int ret;

    ret = 1;
    buf = ft_strnew(0);
    result = NULL;
    while (ret == 1)
    {
        ret = read(0, buf, 1);
        ft_putstr_fd(buf, 0);
        ft_bzero(buf, 1);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Here is my ft_putstr_fd function :

```
 #include "include/libft.h"

  void    ft_putstr_fd(char const *s, int fd)
  {
      write(fd, s, ft_strlen(s));
  }
```

Comment: You need to put the terminal into raw mode, and process the input one character at a time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)